# How to convert a list of tuples full of datetime objects into a list of datetime objects without changing the type?

Tags: python, datetime

I have a list of tuples full od datetime objects like this:

```
list1 = [(datetime1, datetime2), (datetime3, datetime4), (datetime5, datetim6)]
```

I want to convert it to a list of datetime objects, but when i use this code:

```
list2 = [i[j] for i in list1 for j in range(len(i))]
```

The result i got is the list of ints, not datetimes.

I also need later to sort the list2 by time, and then compare the list2 with a list1.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flattening a shallow list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python)

Comment: Can you reproduce your data? The code above should not produce any `int`s.

Comment: You can unzip a list of 3 2-tuples into two 3-tuples with  a, b = zip(*list1) where a = (datetime1, datetime3, datetime5) and b = (datetime2, datetime4, datetime6). To combine them in one tuple just add them with +, convert to a list with list() and sort with sorted, i,e. list2 = sorted(list(a+b)).  Another approach is list2 = [i for s in list(map(list, list1)) for i in s]

Comment: This is not a dupe, the OP's code would already flatten the list

Answer (score 0):

When you add a tuple to a list it adds the inner variables separately, just use:

```
list1 = [("datetime1", "datetime2"), ("datetime3", "datetime4"), ("datetime5", "datetim6")]
list2 = []

for datetime in list1: 
    list2 += datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to sort and flatten do it in one step:

```
from itertools import chain
srt_dates = sorted(chain.from_iterable(list1)
```

If you want to sort just by the time and not the date and time, you can use a lambda as the sort key:

```
from itertools import chain
from datetime import datetime

list1 = [(datetime(2015, 1, 2, 15, 0, 10), datetime(2015, 1, 2, 12, 0, 10)),
         (datetime(2015, 1, 2, 14, 05, 10), datetime(2015, 1, 4, 11, 0, 10))]
srt_dates = sorted(chain.from_iterable(list1), key=lambda x: (x.hour, x.min, x.second))

print(srt_dates)
[datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 4, 11, 0, 10), datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 2, 12, 0, 10), datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 2, 14, 5, 10), datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 2, 15, 0, 10)]
```

The only way  `[i[j] for i in list1 for j in range(len(i))]` would give you a list of ints is if you have reassigned the name `list1` to a list that that has iterables than contain ints.